Xcode tests missing success/failure icons
I seem to have an odd bug in Xcode that I can't seem to fix.  When I run tests, the tests seem to run (the console gives a report), but the test doesn't show the green success checkmark or red x failure icon.

When I run a fresh project I do get the icons

Has anyone else seen this problem and know how to fix?

After doing some git spelunking, I discovered that the issue began when I added cd "${PROJECT_DIR}" ; agvtool bump as a post-build action.  Removing it restored the check-marks on tests.
